# PostgreSQL jsonb_set multiple elements in array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have following jsonb structure in column `recipients` in a table called `mailing`:

```
[
    {
        "text": "Text1",
        "smsId": 1,
        "value": "123456",
        "status": "Sent"
    },
    {
        "text": "Text1",
        "smsId": 2,
        "value": "23456",
        "status": "Sent"
    },
    {
        "text": "Text1",
        "smsId": 3,
        "value": "345678",
        "status": "Sent"
    }]
```

I need to update one field in multiple elements, so the outcome should look like this:

```
[
{
    "text": "Text1",
    "smsId": 1,
    "value": "123456",
    "status": "Delivered"
},
{
    "text": "Text1",
    "smsId": 2,
    "value": "23456",
    "status": "Delivered"
},
{
    "text": "Text1",
    "smsId": 3,
    "value": "345678",
    "status": "Delivered"
}]
```

The most close I got to solution is this:

```
WITH item AS (SELECT mailing_id, ('{' || INDEX-1 || ',status}')::text[] AS PATH
            FROM mailing, jsonb_array_elements(recipients) WITH ORDINALITY arr(recipient, INDEX) 
            WHERE recipient->>'smsId' = any(array['1', '2', '3']))
UPDATE mailing m 
SET recipients = jsonb_set(recipients, item.path, '"Delivered"',FALSE) 
FROM item 
WHERE m.mailing_id = item.mailing_id;
```

But this solution updates only first row, and I am not sure if I should somehow loop this or try different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate modified array elements with `jsonb_agg()`:

```sql
with new_data as (
    select 
        mailing_id, 
        jsonb_agg(
            case when value->>'smsId' = any('{1,2,3}') then value || '{"status": "Delivered"}'
            else value
            end) as recipients
    from mailing
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(recipients)
    group by mailing_id
)
update mailing m 
set recipients = n.recipients
from new_data n
where m.mailing_id = n.mailing_id;
```

Test it in [db<>fidlle](https://dbfiddle.uk/60RF5NYf).